# Magento 2.3 Stamps.com Integration issues with post-back tracking

Tags: magento, magento2, stamps.com

A Magento 2.3 site is experiencing problems with the Stamps.com API module integration. The specific recent issue is that the post-back data does not seem to function. The merchant is expecting to see an order that was "processing" automatically "complete" when they complete the shipping process on Stamps.com software side. They also expect tracking data for that shipment to appear on the Magento order automatically. That is not occuring.

Overview of situation:

- Site is Magento 2.3.4 version
- Merchant admin/shipping manager is using the Software from Stamps on their end
- Stamps.com provided some less than ideal documentation, but some. They provided the Module for the API which is properly installed to the site. So we are using the module provided directly by them without alteration.
- The module is successfully connected between Magento site and Stamps.com and recognizing the orders being imported to the Stamps account.
- When the shipping admin completes the shipment of the order on their end, nothing happens to auto-update the order status or post tracking info to the order inside Magento.
- Shipping admin claims it did work with their previous Magento 1 site (although Magento 1 was a different program).

Here is the official instructions provided by Stamps related to the software method (click on Software tab): https://stamps.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1213/kw/post%20back

I shared these instructions with the shipping admin, and asked them to make sure they were following the recommended settings on their software end. Unfortunately that software is beyond our control or visual, and I have not yet received any actual error details from them or Stamps other than "it does not do anything".

We also reviewed the actual code in the Magento module provided by Stamps.com, and didn't notice anything obvious to indicate a post-back or tracking data feature. There are no specific errors present in the error log on the Magento site.

Is anyone familiar with this module or similar challenges with Stamps and Magento 2 integration? I have attempted to contact Stamps support without any response so far.

Comment: Having the same issue. Inspecting the console when this runs, I see this, but still not helpful:

{"Message":"Unable to connect to the marketplace! Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}

All settings are confirmed as correct.